# Why this code may crash in C++ (pointer return)?

Tags: c++

```
int& subtraction(int& a,int& b) {
    int* pc = new int;
    *pc = a - b;
    return (*pc);
}
```

I run this code on windows it is correct,but when I
do the same thing on Linux it cause some problem.It
does not result in a run-time error,what is the problem.
Thanks

Comment: Other than a potential memory leak and integer underflow, there is no bug in this code.

Comment: What kind of problem does it cause exactly?

Comment: *"it cause some problem"* - are we supposed to guess what the problem is?

Comment: "I run this code" - when you do so, what values do you provide for `a` and `b`? Without that information, your question has zero meaning. "it cause some problem" is not a meaningful problem description. (Tell your doctor "I have some problem. What's wrong?" and see what happens.) See [How to create meaningful, complete and verifiable example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why are you using references here in the first place?  C++ is not Java.

Comment: Who taught you to write code like this? It is utterly dreadful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29316665/962089) sheds some light on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has memory leak. Consider this case

```
int a =5, b =7, c =9;
int & d = subtraction(a,subtraction(b,c));
```

You will lost the reference of the pointer returned by subtraction(b,c) and you would not be able to free the variable.

Comment: It doesn't inherently have a memory leak. Only if you misuse it. The same logic applies to `malloc` and `new`. I'm not saying it's a fun function to use, though.

Comment: What about the reference of subtraction(b,c) reference? That is lost. And that will lead to memory leak.

Comment: @BillLynch: That would be... ill advised.  What you `new`, you must `delete`, not `free()`.