# what happens when the function returning value is a pointer and the returning type is a reference in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

guys, I just got a bonus question from my teacher! Thanks for helping me !!

The sub2 below does not result in a run-time error, but there may be some other
problem. What is the problem?

enter code here

```
int& sub2 ( int& a , int& b ){
int * pc = new int ;
*pc = a - b ;
return (*pc ) ;
}
```

Comment: The return value is not a pointer. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313296/why-this-code-may-crash-in-c-pointer-return

Comment: Results in a memory leak.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Not yet. It depends how the caller captures the result. So far it's just horrible code.

Comment: Put yourself in the position of the caller. They can say `int i = sub2(x, y);`. But they need to do something to `i` to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Not necessarily. Just a requirement for the caller to jump through an extra hoop to avoid one.

Comment: @juanchopanza I wasn't sure if we really should do that guy's homework. I just wanted to give a hint. I'm aware of the caller dependency already.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Unfortunately your hint is wrong.

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't agree: πάνταῥεῖ  is right, because unless you know the inner working of this function, you'd expect it to return a reference that you don't own, so you don't have to care about destruction.

Comment: @Christophe The code doesn't result in a memory leak, period. It is very likely to do so, which I presume is the point of the question. But saying it results in a memory leak is misleading.

Comment: @juanchopanza the function can easily be used within a complex expression, so that the caller can't catch the lvalue.   If it doesn't **result** immediately in a memory leak, it can probably **lead** to such a problem sooner or later. So we are playing with words.

Comment: Yes you are "playing with words" and so far juanchopanza is outright winning the game.

Answer (score 1):

This function MIGHT lead to memory leaks.

- If the user of this function just relies on the signature of the function, he'll assume that the function returns a reference to an object that someone else owns.   Hence the object that was allocated will not be released.
- Of course, if the user is aware of the trick,  he could still delete the object by taking the address of the reference
- If the function is used in a larger expression (which is quite tempting, given the signature), such as `sub(3, sub(2,1))`  he will not get the opportunity to catch the temporary reference.

Note that this function MIGHT also throw a `bad_alloc` if there's an issue with the memory allocation.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I understand that it can lead to Memory leak when the user doesn't use delete(), but why it can lose the temporary reference?? sub(2,1)  returns a reference that does not refer to a local variable which can lead to that problem, but it refers to a pointer allocated in heap where compiler can not delete it automatically..  I think that if the pointer changes to int c, and the function returns the reference to the local variable c, then it can lead to referencing problem, right?

Comment: Exactly,  if you return a reference to a local variable, that local variable will be destroyed upon return.  So the reference refers to an object that no longer exists (ouch!).  In fact, the best way to write this is to return by value: the compiler then manages himselfs the temporary storage needed.

Comment: please see my question again! now there is not a local variable, but a real pointer allocated in heap, in which case the reference to the pointer will not easily be disjointed, so why did you claim the third opinion?

Comment: Because sub(3, sub(2,1)) will cause sub(2,1) to be called. the reference that is returned will be provided as argument to sub(3, ...).  As soon as the expression is evaluated, all temporaries are destroyed (i.e. the temporary reference is destroyed, and not the object that is referred to).  The compler will never automatically delete an object create with `new`  if you didn't provide code (for example in a destructor) to do it.